# Filesystem Hierarchy Standard - Where to put sourceable functions?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I have a few bash scripts running system checks. These scripts source configuration options from a file /etc/healthchecks/config.

Along with the config file, I have a shared functions file. The scripts should be able to source that file and run the functions therein.

Based on the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard, where should I put the shared functions file? It's not a configuration, so it doesn't seem like it belongs in /etc, but it's also not being executed so /usr/bin seems incorrect. Maybe /usr/lib?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should put your `healthchecks` executables in /usr/local/bin or in /opt/bin. If you see your folder /opt is empty, means your linux distribution doesn't use it. So, the suitable place would be /usr/local.

/usr/local and /opt are where every "manual" package/program must be placed. /usr is for packages managed by package managers (i.e, dpkg). /opt is the "standard place" for manual packages according to FHS, but debian distros use /usr/local instead.

For configuration files, they must be placed on /usr/local/etc, since /etc is for configuration files of automatic packages and other system programs.

The correct place for your shared functions is then /usr/local/share (/usr/share is for shared files of automatic packages). Every file which is designed to be read-only and independent of the arquitecture belongs to /usr/share or /usr/local/share (if they are own by "automatic" or "manual" packages).

/usr/lib is for dynamic and static binary libraries (.so or .a), and not for "interpreted" libraries/functions.

Usually, interpreters have different subfolders in /etc/share/ for each version, and inside each version folder, different folders for scripts, locales, tests, samples and so on.

If some day you create an official repository for your package `healthchecks`, you could migrate your /usr/local/healthchecks contents to /usr/healthchecks and /etc/healthchecks.

Comment: I went ahead and deleted my answer because 1) yours covers the topic well enough, and 2) `libexec` technically isn't part of the FHS yet. It's present in the [3.0 draft](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.lfs.beyond.devel/21616) and [Redhat's Overview of the FHS](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/s1-filesystem-fhs.html), but isn't technically part of the FHS yet. (use it if you want, basically)

Answer (score 1):

I generally try to keep site specific things outside of these reserved system areas.  You might consider using your own top-level directory hierarchy as when using system areas special site files can easily get lost or forgotten during system evolution.  Another possibility could be /usr/local/etc.....